# Pass a Full Path Through Different Functions in PS Modules

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-module

What is the best way to declare full paths in Powershell?  I am writing a module that needs to pass full file path variables (ex: $Backup = C:\backups\file1.bak) through multiple psm1 files and is called remotely.

Right now, I need to pass a fully qualified path to Powershell and have it do a lot of different things with it.  It seems to work fine when it's all in 1 functional script, otherwise, the path doesn't actually go through to other functions written in other PSM1 files, but all other variables do.  It seems to just output a null value.

First I have a FileValidator script which among other things, will find the latest filename in the path, and then concat the latest filename, with the path.  Perhaps I need to use joinpath somewhere to fix this is.  The code to get the fully qualified path that isn't exporting to other PSM1 files is:

```
Param: [string] $BackupPath, #= "Z:\backupsfldr\subfldr\"

$LatestSQLBackupDBFileName = Get-ChildItem $BackupPath | Where-Object{($_.LastWriteTime -gt "2014/02/01") -and ($_.Name -like "$DBname*.bak")} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | select -ExpandProperty name 

$FQNBackup = get-item($BackupPath + $LatestSQLBackupDBFileName)
```

As you can see, I was testing the output of $FQNBackup in various places but it just made things worse.  I'm not sure how to define this in the modules or how to cast/convert it.  After declaring the $FQNBackup variable as listed above, I then modify it by trying to do this as found else where on stackoverflow earlier:

```
$FQNBackup = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($FQNBackup)
```

I've tried converting it to a string as well but I might be doing it wrong.  It seems like I should be able to:

1- Get the path

2- Convert to string

3- Pass the value as a string
    to other modules.

However is this 'bad' from an architecture design view?  Should I just keep it the same object type instead as it jumps from different psm's?  That is the real question.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense as it is. You said you have 3 scripts, but posted only one, plus a somehow related(?) code snippet. In the text you say the function name is `Invoke-RestoreDB`, but in the code the name seems to be `Invoke-DBRestore`. How do your code and the function calls actually look like? And how exactly does the path you want to pass along "not go through"? How does the first code snippet fit in with the rest of your code?

Comment: As a side note: you do realize that the code in your first code snippet obtains a `FileInfo` object, expands its `Name` property, concatenates that name back to the path from which the object was retrieved, only to retrieve the very same `FileInfo` object whose `Name` property had been expanded before, don't you? If you need the path, expand the object's `FullName` property instead of the `Name` property. If you need the object, don't bother expanding anything.

Comment: Thanks, yes, there's a lot that needs to be refactored before I release this and I'll use the -FullName property, that's much better.

Comment: I wanted to keep the question really light and not dig into all the other script functionality so I just listed the things that were relevant to the main question.  How would you recommend declaring a path which is formed from a file path and a file name, and how to call that in other functions/scripts within a module?

Comment: Edited question and got rid of the extra fluff.

Comment: Wait I think I just got it to work by using join-path.  Will update answer shortly if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to construct a path from 2 strings you'd normally use the [`Join-Path`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849799.aspx) cmdlet, e.g. like this:

```
PS C:\> Join-Path 'C:\some\folder' 'file.ext'
C:\some\folder\file.ext
```

However, when handling existing files like you do, you could simply use the file object's `FullName` property:

```psh
$FQNBackup = Get-ChildItem $BackupPath | Where-Object {
  $_.LastWriteTime -gt "2014/02/01" -and $_.Name -like "$DBname*.bak"
} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1 -Expand FullName
```

Strings can be passed into functions via string arguments, e.g. like this:

```psh
function Foo {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Bar
  )

  # do stuff
}

Foo -Bar 'some string'
```

Comment: Yup that was EXACTLY right, I just figured that out a few minutes ago.  Setting this as the answer.